# DroidScript - TCP receiving at any moment

Tags: javascript, android, tcp, receiver, droidscript

Ok so for the TCP client in DroidScript, what do I do so that it can receive data from the server at any moment?

The example that is provided shows receiving once only after sending data to the server.

How would i set it up to receive data from the server at any given moment?

I have already tried: net.SetOnReceive and nothing has happened, though i have confirmed data is being sent from the server to the app.

I have also tried net.ReceiveText but I've only received one input from server... but no more after that.

So if anyone could please help?

Screenshot of code:
http://js.x10.bz/ss/i/ZNCj.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DroidScript TCP sockets are client only (not server).  Try using a WebSockets instead and check on the DroidScript forum here:-

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/androidscript/t1QzCgGZrH8/0S8xYbByjNsJ